# DialogFlow Regex Entity not being captured in Training Phrase

Tags: regex, entity, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to make a DialogFlow bot which returns the height weight of a  person, given the policy number. Policy Number is an alphanumeric string on 10 characters with "AA" (2 A's) in the start and then 8 random digits.

I've made a regex entity for the same.

```
^(?i)a{2}\d{8}$
```

But in the training phrase whenever I type a policy number it is not being mapped to the policyNumber entity. I'm fairly new to DialogFlow and this is the first time I'm making a bot.

So, can anybody guide me with what I'm doing wrong.

Here are some of the screenshots.

Training Phrases:

[image: Link]

Here are some of the warnings:

[image: Link]

policyNumber Regex Entity:

[image: Link]

Comment: The anchors match at the start and end of the string, is the input for the pattern a token, or whole text? If the latter, try `(?i)\ba{2}\d{8}\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved after adding 10 training phrases and manually mapping the "regex entity".